# Spark on windows 10 not working

Tags: apache-spark, windows-10

Im trying to get spark working on win10. When i try to run spark shell i get this error :

> 'Spark\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin..\jars""\ is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
>
> Failed to find Spark jars directory. You need to build Spark before running this program.

I am using a pre-built spark for hadoop 2.7 or later. I have installed java 8, eclipse neon, python 2.7, scala 2.11, gotten winutils for hadoop 2.7.1 And i still get this error.

When I donwloaded spark it comes in the tgz, when extracted there is another tzg inside, so i extracted it also and then I got all the bin folders and stuff. I need to access spark-shell. Can anyone help?

EDIT:
Solution i ended up using:

1) Virtual box

2) Linux mint

Comment: Could you post the complete error details so we get to know the issue better?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while building Spark. You can move the extracted folder to C:\

Refer this:
http://techgobi.blogspot.in/2016/08/configure-spark-on-windows-some-error.html

Answer (score 1):

You are probably giving the wrong folder path to Spark bin.

Just open the command prompt and change directory to the `bin` inside the spark folder.

Type `spark-shell` to check.

Refer: [Spark on win 10](https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

"On Windows, I found that if it is installed in a directory that has a space in the path (C:\Program Files\Spark) the installation will fail. Move it to the root or another directory with no spaces."
OR 
If you have installed Spark under “C:\Program Files (x86)..” replace 'Program Files (x86)' with Progra~2 in the PATH env variable and SPARK_HOME user variable.