# The system can't find the path specified spark-shell on windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

I am trying to install `spark` on my local. It is giving below error when running spark-shell

The system can't find the path specified

I have updated all environmental variables like JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME, PATH variables but still getting the error.
[image]

Comment: Can you show the files under ```$SPARK_HOME/bin```? And also the screenshot of error after you run spark-shell

Comment: Can you please try adding %SPARK_HOME%\conf directory on PATH as well?

Comment: Added %SPARK_HOME%\conf to path but no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark on windows 10 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296802/spark-on-windows-10-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have changed the JAVA_HOME path resolved my issue.

Space in JAVA_HOME caused the issue. Spark will not be installed if you have spaces in your java path.